# Found nil when assigning image in UICollectionView

Tags: image, swift3, nsurl

As a beginner in writing swift code, I am getting error in the following code:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = self.collectionView?.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell

    let imageURL = NSURL(string: usersImageArray[indexPath.row])
    print("The image url is \(imageURL)")
    let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: imageURL as! URL)

    cell.userImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData as! Data)
    cell.userName.text = usersNameArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

The imageURL does contain an image url and the imageData does contain image Data but still I get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

I have seen and read other questions and answers and tried but still I can not find the problem. What exactly is causing the error though it does contain the URL and image data?
[image]

**UPDATED:**
My CollectionViewCell Class:

import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView!



@IBOutlet weak var userName: UILabel!


override func layoutSubviews() {

    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.makeImageRound()

}

func makeImageRound(){
    self.userImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.userImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.userImage.frame.size.width/2.0
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have given the URL like this : optional(imageurl), it takes as it is , so you should avoid optional(. ) , to avoid this use '!' After userimagearray[indexpath.row]!

Try this and print imageurl and then see what happens

Try this

```
 if imagedata == nil{

        //give some image 
   }
else{
       //give imagedata here
    }
```

And take reuseidentifier = "cell"

Not cell whatever you take in a storyboard tableviewcell

Comment: I did it but the thing is that it gives an error on the line where it assigns to the Image. cell.userImage.image line. I unwrapped it and it prints the url fine. When it goes on to the next line , assigning the Imagedata to image, it crashes again

Comment: I just updated the question and added my CollectionViewCellClass where my IBOutlets are defined. The imageData is being fetched from Firebase and is perfectly fine I guess

Comment: Before this error I was getting the assertion fail error so I added this line in my viewDidLoad() "self.collectionView?.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)". It solved that

Comment: Hey you didn't give reuseidentifier

Comment: I tried what you said before too and it executes the else block >>else {
           cell.userImage.image  = UIImage(data: imageData as! Data)
        }. After that it gives error on this line

Comment: reuseIdentifier is defined as private let reuseIdentifier = "CollectionViewCell" at the top of my file

Comment: Did you give it in storyboard and take that in cell for row index method

Comment: Yes in my story board I have given my collection view a collectionViewCell class which I made

Comment: I have tried a lot of things but it still gives me error while assigning. There is something wrong with the IBOutlet maybe. I did something like this now cell.userImage.image = UIImage(named: "home.png"). It still says unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping